# django query accessing foreign key data

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

Apology if this is a duplicate but I could not find any satisfying answer for this case. Maybe I am doing something fundamentally wrong, like need to define models in a different way.I am also very new to django.So suggestions will be really helpful.

Suppose I have my models like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
class Team(Group):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Players(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now if I for example, want a queryset of all players by the Team model what can I do?
I have the foreign key in the Players model and not in Team model. So something like `Team.objects.filter(logic)` is needed to get all players. But exactly what logic will work here?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django allows you get access to related objects in reverse way. It calling reverse relation. And related manager objects using for it. You can find more details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects). In your specifc case you can get players using `players_set` team's attribute:

```
team = Team.objects.get(pk=1)
players = team.players_set.all()
```

Answer (score 3):

Django ORM also can filter by relation. these kind of filtering is valid for all kind of relations.

```
 players = Players.objects.filter(team__id = 1)
```

in case you have the team object.

```
players = Players.objects.filter(team = team)
```